# How to pull an integer value from NSRange?

Tags: objective-c, integer, nsrange

I have an NSRange and need to break a string into two substrings on either side of this NSRange.  How do I get an integer value (like the index) out of an NSRange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSRange` struct consists of two integers - the `location` and the `length`.

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
    NSUInteger location;
    NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

It looks like `location` and `location+length` are the two expressions that you are looking for - the ranges for the left and right substring are as follows:

```
NSRange prefixRange = NSMakeRange(0, myRange.location);
NSUInteger pos =myRange.location+myRange.length;
NSRange suffixRange = NSMakeRange(pos, myString.length - pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but in **Swift 4** (and perhaps earlier) there are new `upperBound` and `lowerBound` convenience properties on `NSRange`:

```
print(myRange) // Range: {13, 4}    
range.lowerBound // 13
range.upperBound // 17
```

Hopefully that helps someone else.